# Visualization of particular integration using trigonometric function

Tags: integration, functions, trigonometry, rational-functions, visualization

I know that when you're trying to integrate something, and by chance, appears somewhere something of the form :

$$ \sqrt {1 - x^2} ; \sqrt {1 + x^2}$$
or something similar, it is known to replace x by a trigonometric function, here

$$ \sin y \, ; \, \sinh^{-1} y $$

Inversely, if you're stuck with trigonometric function like in this case :
$$ \frac{1}{\sin x}$$
it is good to use Tangent half-angle substitution, or also called Weierstrass substitution in order to create a rationnal function.

Finally (and that's the best), when you have any function and you see that the integral is even or odd, it is recommanded to use the substitution of either $x = \cos y$ or $x = \sin x$. I don't know how this law is called in English, but in french we call it *"règle de Bioche"*.

> My question is the following : Why is it always working? Why those
> earmarks implies that doing this substitution is going to work ?
>
> I was believing that maybe rational and trigonometric functions have a link, that somehow, trigonometric function and roots are linked ?
>
> Nevertheless, when I plot the graph, I don't see anything. Maybe someone has a better
> intuition and have an explanation of why those substitution works, and
> how is it visible.

If you need more example to understand what I mean, please take a look at this :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1-xHNPMpB0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ria48cFHkBw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuEmoUU60FY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rRaDRQ7ans

Moreover, another example is Euler Substitution, where does it comes from ??? it is so weird...

Comment: “Always” is a tricky thing when it comes to integration. You can find several different ways to compute one integral and the “best” varies from person to person. As for substitutions, even those earmarks may not guarantee it is going to work. For instance $\int\frac{1}{1+\cos^4x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ becomes $\int\frac{t^2+1}{t^4+2t^2+2}\,\mathrm{d}t$ if you make the Weierstrauss substitution $t=\tan x$ which depending on the person is much worse.

Comment: but my question was about visualization and not about integration method